# Size of PriorityQueue increases when non-comparable objects are added

Tags: java, priority-queue

Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        PriorityQueue<A> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        System.out.println("Size of queue is " + queue.size()); // prints 0
        queue.add(new A()); // does not throw an exception
        try {
            queue.add(new A()); // this time, an exception is thrown
        } catch (ClassCastException ignored) {
            System.out.println("An exception was thrown");
        }
        System.out.println("Size of queue is " + queue.size()); // prints 2
    }

} 

class A { } // non-comparable object
```

In this code, a non-comparable object is first added to a `PriorityQueue`. This code works fine, [as already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32318500).

Then, a second object is added to this queue. As expected per [`PriorityQueue.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#add-E-) Javadoc, a `ClassCastException` is thrown because the second object is not comparable to the first one.

However, it seems that the size of the queue was increased although an exception was thrown: the second print statement outputs 2 instead of 1.

Is this behaviour expected? If so, what is the reason behind this and where is it documented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to GrepCode.com's [version of the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#PriorityQueue.add%28java.lang.Object%29), it looks like it may be a bug in their implementation.

All the add function does is call

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return offer(e);
}
```

The offer function looks like this

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    modCount++;
    int i = size;
    if (i >= queue.length)
        grow(i + 1);
    size = i + 1;
    if (i == 0)
        queue[0] = e;
    else
        siftUp(i, e);
    return true;
}
```

You'll notice that size = i + 1 is called before the item is actually inserted via siftUp. When siftUp is called, the very first thing that it does is try to cast to Comparable and throws the exception before actually inserting the item. Therefore it increments the size without actually inserting an item.

Answer (score 2):

The source code for [`offer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#PriorityQueue.offer%28java.lang.Object%29) (called by `add`) reveals the invalid state that occurs when passing a non-`Comparable` object to a `PriorityQueue` that doesn't have a `Comparator`.

```
public boolean More offer(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    modCount++;
    int i = size;
    if (i >= queue.length)
        grow(i + 1);
    size = i + 1;
    if (i == 0)
        queue[0] = e;
    else
        siftUp(i, e);
    return true;
}
```

The size is modified before `siftUp` is called.  The `siftUp` method, normally responsible for inserting the element into the queue, (eventually) throws the `ClassCastException`, but the size has already been modified, leaving the size incorrect.

It appears not to be documented that the `size` will be incremented even if a `ClassCastException` occurs.  A simple fix would be to place the line `size = i + 1;` after the if/else and before the return statement.